# Windows Phone invalid license in my app?

Tags: windows-phone-7, visual-studio-2012, windows-phone

When I run my app in the emulator (either Debug or Release build) I get the following error:

> "App Name" license is invalid.  Please purchase the product.

And gives me the "uninstall" or "buy" options.

Notes:

- This app ran on the emulator fine until recent VS update.
- I tried
  cleaning the project and didn't help.
- This is using Windows Phone 7.1 emulator.

[This](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpdevelop/thread/2d1354a8-b5d1-49d1-9cd7-eb58ce256cc9/) is the only relevant information I've found so far but their error was happening on the device, not the emulator.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: well have you tried restarting the emulator?

Comment: Yes. I also restarted the PC and the error persists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try running "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft XDE\8.0\XdeCleanup.exe". This will recreate the emulator for you and should clean out any bad state.

If this continues to happen on any app (including, say, HelloWorld), then can you please share out a xap?